# "TypeError: user.timeout is not a function"

Tags: discord, discord.js, typeerror

I'd like to make a command that when used temporarily auto-mutes the person on Discord.

The problem: when I try to run the command, I get this error: "TypeError: user.timeout is not a function".
Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {

    name: 'cramptés',
    description: 'quoi ? t\'as les cramptés ?',
    permission: 'Aucune',
    dm: false,
    category: 'Utilitaire',

    async run(bot, interaction, args) {

        await interaction.reply(
            {
                content: `C'est dommage d'avoir les cramptés`,
                ephemeral: true,
                components: [],


            }
        )
        let user = interaction.user.id 
        user.timeout(600000, "fallait pas avoir les cramptés")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interaction.user.id` returns a `string` and it doesn't have a `.timeout()` function.

To timeout the member:

```js
interaction.member.timeout(600000, "fallait pas avoir les cramptés")
```

Reference: [GuildMember#timeout()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout)